# compile time check for enums

Tags: c, types, enums

Consider the following snippet:

```
enum ids {
   ID1 = 1,
   ID2 = 2,
   ID3 = 3,
};
```

So this list can be extended with new ID. Is there a way in the C language to provide a compile time check ensuring that these IDs do not repeat each other, i.e. the following could be caught because ID100 is equal to ID2:

```
enum ids {
   ID1 = 1,
   ID2 = 2,
   ID3 = 3,
   ...
   ID100 = 2
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it is expressly allowed that multiple enum constants associated with the same enum type map to the same value.

Comment: @John Bollinger, thanks I will take a look. Isn't it the c++ only solution?

Comment: No.  The dupe does have some answers that are C++-specific, but the accepted and highest-voted one is not among those.